# Why "rows["epic_week"] = epic_week" does not work?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to add a new column to pandas data frame. When I want to update the by using iterrows() function, the "rows["epic_week"]  = epic_week" does not work.

```
date_counter = 5
pre_date = df.Date[0]
epic_week = 9
df["epic_week"] = 0
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    if rows["Date"] != pre_date:
        date_counter += 1
        pre_date = rows["Date"]
        if date_counter > 7:
            date_counter = 1
            epic_week += 1
        rows["epic_week"] = epic_week
```

Comment: Try `df.loc[index, "epic_week"] = epic_week`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the second note here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html. You are iterating over your dataframe so you shouldn't try to modify it as you iterate over it.

You could try making a copy of the df and iterating over the copy while updating the original, or save the changes you'd like to add in a data structure while you're in the loop then add them to the df once you're done iterating over it.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change the last line as shown below

```
date_counter = 5
pre_date = df.Date[0]
epic_week = 9
df["epic_week"] = 0
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    if rows["Date"] != pre_date:
        date_counter += 1
        pre_date = rows["Date"]
        if date_counter > 7:
            date_counter = 1
            epic_week += 1
        rows.at[index, "epic_week"] = epic_week # This will work
```